# burning a multi-session cd into iso

Tags: disk-utility, dmg, optical-drive

I have a multi-session (osx/windows) cd that I'd like to create an iso from. Is there a way to create a single iso file with all the sessions included in it?

Output from `diskutil list disk2` is below. The identifier for the optical drive on my Mac is `disk2`.

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical): 
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *591.9 MB   disk2 
   1:     Apple_partition_scheme ⁨⁩                        515.4 MB   disk2s1 
   2:        Apple_partition_map ⁨⁩                        32.3 KB    disk2s1s1
                    (free space)                         276.8 MB   - 
   3:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Master Install CD       238.6 MB   disk2s1s2
 –
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: everything listed on this [earlier post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331938/create-disk-image-which-can-be-read-on-windows)

Comment: Please list the things you‘ve tried and how they failed, you will only get the same answers otherwise.

Comment: Using disk utility to create a hybrid image: I have osx big sur and there is no "hybrid image (HFS+/ISO/UDF)" option available in disk utility

Comment: Using disk utility followed by hdiutil: the image is mountable in windows, but only it only sees the osx partition.

Comment: There used to be a third answer posted by David Anderson but the post has been deleted.

Comment: Please edit the question with details, including screenshots. Things tend to get lost in comments.

Comment: Also there is no deleted answer on the link you referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked may times in the passed. Although, multi-session (osx/windows) was probably not mentioned in the past. The Snow Leopard DVD (OS X 10.6) has an additional session containing the Windows Boot Camp software. Below are the instructions for creating an ISO from this type of DVD.

I did test the Snow Leopard ISO using both macOS and Windows 10. Both operating systems open the ISO to different sessions.

### Create your own ISO

Use these steps to make an ISO copy of your DVD:

1. While your Mac is started from macOS (OS X), insert the DVD in an external optical USB drive. (You can also use an internal optical drive, if you have an older Mac with an internal optical drive that still works.)
2. After the media mounts in the Finder, open Disk Utility from the Utilities folder (choose Go > Utilities).
3. Select the optical drive so it's highlighted in the Disk Utility window.
4. Choose File > New Image, and then select your DVD or from the submenu.
5. Choose DVD/CD master from the Image Format menu, then choose none from the Encryption menu.
6. Give the new file a name, then click Save. If prompted, enter an administrator user name and password. A progress bar appears while the image file is created (it might take some time to create the image file).
7. After imaging is done, eject your disc. If you're using an external optical drive, disconnect it from the USB port after the disc ejects.
8. From the Finder, locate the disk image file you created earlier. Single click on it to select it, then press the Enter or Return key on your keyboard to rename the file. Change the disk image file extension from .cdr to .iso. When prompted, click "Use .iso" to verify this change.
   [image]

Below is the output from `diskutil list disk3`. The identifier for the optical drive on my Mac is `disk3`.

```
/dev/disk3 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *7.8 GB     disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map ⁨⁩                        30.7 KB    disk3s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI ⁨⁩                        1.0 GB     disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Mac OS X Install DVD⁩    6.7 GB     disk3s3
```

Comment: I have a non bootable multi-session cd that I am trying to creating an ISO out of. I did what you suggested, where I tried both creating the image by selecting either the optical drive name or the mounted partition. Neither of that worked. When creating the image by selecting the drive name, the resulting iso (cdr) file is not mountable by either osx / win. And when creating the image by selecting the mounted partition, then the resulting iso is mountable in both, but in windows it only sees the osx partition.

Comment: And before writing this question, I had seen your (and others) [earlier post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331938/create-disk-image-which-can-be-read-on-windows). None of that worked for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you insert the CD in the optical drive and post the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: /dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *591.9 MB   disk2
   1:     Apple_partition_scheme ⁨⁩                        515.4 MB   disk2s1
   2:        Apple_partition_map ⁨⁩                        32.3 KB    disk2s1s1
                    (free space)                         276.8 MB   -
   3:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Master Install CD    238.6 MB   disk2s1s2

Comment: I posted the output from `diskutil list` for the Snow Leopard DVD. YourCD is using a different format. This is probably why my answer did not work.